# React Accordion: how to fetch data for each expanded item onclick and not show same data for all items?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am iterating and rendering multiple products. I can see the details for each product onclick (when I open the accordion). The way I have it now, when I press lets say on product2 and I have in total 5 products, all products will show details for product2. I tried so many things such as fetching the data not in my Parent component but inside the child component but nothing works. Any ideas would be so great! Thanks!

```
const App = () => {
    const {state: {isFetchingDetailsForProduct, detailsForProduct}, fetchDetailsForProduct} = useContext(SearchContext);
    
    const getDetails = async (product) => {
        await fetchDetailsForProduct(product) //api call to fetch details for chosen product
    };
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
                return (
                    <Product
                        product={item}
                        getDetails={getDetails}
                        details={detailsForProduct}
                        isFetching={isFetchingDetailsForProduct}
                    />
                )
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        />
    )
}

const Product = ({getDetails, product, details, isFetching}) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    return (
              <>
            <ListItem.Accordion
                content={
                    <>
                        <ListItem>
                            <View>
                                <Text>{product.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </ListItem>
                    </>
                }
                isExpanded={expanded}
                onPress={() => {
                    setExpanded(!expanded);
                    getDetails(product.name)
                }}
            >
                    <Details
                        isFetching={isFetching}
                        details={details} 
                    />
            </ListItem.Accordion>
        </>
```

Ps. the product data and the details data come from different sources, otherwise it would of course solve the problem.

```
const data = [{name: "product1", category: "abc",...}, {},...];
const details = [{product. "product1", color: "red",...},{},...]
```

Comment: Maybe move `getDetails` and `detailsForProduct` into `Product` and keep `detailsForProduct` in a `useState`?

Comment: I did that too and still same problem. the issue is as I understand that once I click to open the accordion the following: if lets say i have 2 of 5 accordions open,then i get twice same data, because i eventually fetch data with the last props passed to my onclick. so the first opened accordion filled with data re renders when I open the second and gets 'filled' with props and data of the last opened accordion

Comment: Could you add the code that comes after `<ListItem.Accordion` to your question?

Comment: I just did. I must have accidentally removed it or so. sorry about that!!